# TempData working with a delay and is null for the first time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

in Asp.net MVC: TempData is null for the first redirect and in the second redirect works, sometimes works good, sometimes get the third redirect
I need to refresh the page several times to see the effectiveness of TempData
it's working on localhost good but on the server not working properly.
For Example:
in below this code in "VerifyPaymentView" action tempdata["VerifyInfo"] is null for the first time and you need to refresh the page several times to get the content of tempdata

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Verify(int id)
    {
        var verifyInfo = await VerifyPayment(id, new List<Func<HttpRequestBase, Presenter, PayData, Task<VerifyCallbackData>>>()
        {
            SetPackage,
            SetExam,
            SetQuestionBankId,
            SetQuestionBankGroupId,
            SetReportCardLink,
            VerifySpace
        });

        if (verifyInfo == null)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyPaymentView");
        }

        TempData["VerifyInfo"] = verifyInfo;

        return RedirectToAction("VerifyPaymentView");
    }

 public ActionResult VerifyPaymentView()
    {
        var userId = User.GetUserId();
        var isLogin = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (TempData["Error"] != null)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = true;
            return View();
        }

        if (TempData["VerifyInfo"] != null)
        {
            var verifyInfo = (VerifyInfo)TempData["VerifyInfo"];
            return View(verifyInfo);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TempData.Keep() in VerifyPaymentView which will allow you to read the value without marking it for deletion.

```
@{
    TempData.Keep("VerifyInfo");
}
```

Comment: the problem is not to keep value after reading, the problem is I need to refresh VerifyPaymentView page to get the TempData value, most of the times not working for the first time on the server